# How stable is Facebook profile url?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using user profile picture I get from Facebook SDK. Do I need to cache photo or url is enough to cache? Is it possible once url will invalid? Is it possible once loading url will not be possible Facebook provided?

I.e. my profile pic url is here, still able to load photo, but for how long it is available? https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/12592388_10208092332220228_4815371318375925057_n.jpg?oh=cc3ba223afc6f123e381ef18fabbc40d&oe=57E3BD91

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not store any URL of the Facebook CDNs, Facebook cannot guarantee that it will still be available later, with the same URL. If you need it later, download it to your own server...or get it with the API again.